# After upgrading npm, webpack errors showing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

After I upgraded the npm package to the latest one, 8.2.0 I started getting problems in react application. here is the screen shot.

[image]

here is what I see in console:

> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
> react-dom.development.js:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: run is not defined
> at Object../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:199910)
> at **webpack_require** (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:857)
> at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
> at Object../node_modules/react-dom/index.js (:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:225957)
> at **webpack_require** (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:857)
> at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
> at Module. (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:4506)
> at Module../src/index.tsx (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:4643)
> at **webpack_require** (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:857)
> at fn (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:151)
> at Object.1 (:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:4657)
> at **webpack_require** (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:857)
> at checkDeferredModules (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46)
> at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33)
> at :3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1
> webpackHotDevClient.js:138 src/App.tsx

However when I build it and run it using nginx or serve -s build the app runs just fine as it should. it's just that npm start works and app shows all these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after researching much I was able to solve the issue by issuing two commands

```
npm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

it's like reinstalling the project dependencies. No change in code or any other file was needed. I still do not know what caused it and why the dependency suddenly got issues with np upgrade but now it's working again.